# Operation not permitted during docker build

Tags: docker, permissions, hypriot

I am trying to build a trivial image from the follwing Dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/ubuntu:20.04
RUN touch tmp.txt
```

But I receive the error Operation not permitted

```
$ docker build .    
Sending build context to Docker daemon  71.68kB  
Step 1/2 : FROM arm32v7/ubuntu:20.04
---> bcf7edb34eae
Step 2/2 : RUN touch tmp.txt
---> Running in 686d92e86a27
touch: setting times of 'tmp.txt': Operation not permitted
```

This happens on an Raspberry Pi flashed with Hypriot OS, while the same builds just fine on my laptop (x86 and cross building).

I get it is some kind of permission error, but I am able to run `sudo` commands without problems, hence I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Are you sure about  that `arm32v7` architecture? Modern Raspberry Pi units have 64-bit processors. Try changing 'FROM' directive to `FROM ubuntu:20.04` so Docker will pick architecture up for you.

Comment: Yes, `getconf LONG_BIT` outputs 32, using a 64 bit image gives `exec error`, the 64bit is being beta tested, see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34715/is-raspbian-for-the-raspberry-pi-2-b-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os)

Comment: It honestly looks like the docker image is just faulty. It should set a working directory where writing is for sure allowed before creating a file, for example to /tmp, and apparently it doesn't. You should contact whoever maintains it.

Comment: The image is just the default ubuntu one, and it builds fine when I cross-build it on the laptop.

Comment: I am talking about the "touch tmp.txt" command, which clearly is custom. Where this command is executed matters, a docker build runs in a very normal linux system like filesystem with /home, /tmp, etc directories and all of that, and you can change directories and use permissions like on a normal full linux system. WORKDIR is possibly what you are looking for, or just use cd /tmp && touch tmp.txt in one line for example.

Comment: Ah sorry, this is a dummy file I generated to debug the problem. The original Dockerfile is much more articulated, but gives the same problem when I try to create a file. I don't understand why the same Dockerfile works on the laptop though.  
 Edit: the original Dockerfile does use WORKDIR to change the directory to a previously created one, but it still fails.

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution [here](https://docs.linuxserver.io/faq#my-host-is-incompatible-with-images-based-on-ubuntu-focal), based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-papermerge/issues/4)

The solution is to update `libseccomp2` executing the following on the Raspberry Pi:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libseccomp/libseccomp2_2.4.4-1~bpo10+1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libseccomp2_2.4.4-1~bpo10+1_armhf.deb
```

Afterwards, the image builds as expected

Comment: The file does not exist (anymore). I tried http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libseccomp/libseccomp2_2.5.1-1~bpo10+1_armhf.deb and it worked